# Mobile Web Push Notification - What is the typical Delivery rate? Can it be 100%?

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I am trying to use mobile web push notifications to enable chat on my site. Since I have a use case to remind users about any updates on the chat - I want to use push notification on the web.

I have experimented with web push notification using FCM and the delivery rate hovers around 60% for me. It is either not delivered (no delivered_time stamp) or gives a 400 error - "Invalid Token format"

I need to understand if there are any improvements I can make to increase the delivery rate? Can it be 100%?
Also, does notifying on mobile web for chat seem to be a valid use case for push notifications or do you think there are better alternatives?

Dump of my  log - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oiGkfgiRtoDZTT6bSu9UduHj6IQljj5bFDbliDvbI8I/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Unlike GCM(now FCM) notifications, web notifications need the browser to be open(at least in the background) for them to be delivered. And There are still a lot of anolmalies in the system since it is still marked as an experimental technology. Even though the delivery rate can't be 100%, it becomes more and more stable with every release and the future is bright for web-push-notifications.
We experience a delivery rate of 60-70% on tracking impressions of the campaigns for 36 hours.

Comment: Thanks Dhruv. Any ideas on what are the reasons for delivery rate not being 100%? Any factors which we can tweak to get a better delivery rate? Also, doesn't web push also use FCM as the push service?

Comment: Network delay while fetching payload for the notification is the biggest culprit that I faced. Another one is push-token gets updated but the backend is not informed about it so it keeps sending pushes to an old token and expects Impressions. 
And FCM is used for Chrome and Opera but Mozilla uses a different service.